# android drive api this file is not openable

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

New to Google Drive API and can't seem to read the contents of a Google Doc file. I am able to read the metadata but the file will not "open". I get this Error Code 10, Status{statusCode=This file is not openable., resolution=null}. How do I access the content of Google doc?

```html
private void open() {
        Log.w(TAG, mSelectedFileDriveId.getResourceId());
        DriveFile driveFile = mSelectedFileDriveId.asDriveFile();

        driveFile.getMetadata(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallbacks<DriveResource.MetadataResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(@NonNull DriveResource.MetadataResult metadataResult) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Title: "+ metadataResult.getMetadata().getTitle());
                Log.w(TAG, "Filename: "+ metadataResult.getMetadata().getOriginalFilename());
                Log.w(TAG, "MimeType: "+ metadataResult.getMetadata().getMimeType());
                Log.w(TAG, "DriveId: "+ metadataResult.getMetadata().getDriveId());
                Log.w(TAG, "Description: "+ metadataResult.getMetadata().getDescription());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Status status) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to get metadata");
            }
        });

        driveFile.open(mGoogleApiClient, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null).setResultCallback(driveContentsResultResultCallbacks);
        mSelectedFileDriveId = null;
    }
```

```html
private final ResultCallbacks<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult> driveContentsResultResultCallbacks = new ResultCallbacks<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(@NonNull DriveApi.DriveContentsResult driveContentsResult) {
            Log.i(TAG, "File contents opened");

            // Read from the input stream an print to LOGCAT
            DriveContents driveContents = driveContentsResult.getDriveContents();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(driveContents.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String contentsAsString = builder.toString();
            Log.i(TAG, contentsAsString);

            // Close file contents
            driveContents.discard(mGoogleApiClient);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Status status) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Error while opening the file contents");
            Log.w(TAG, "Status: "+status.getStatus());
            Log.w(TAG, "Status Code: "+status.getStatusCode());
            Log.w(TAG, "Status Message: "+status.getStatusMessage());
        }
    };
```

```html
1ysPUyGHKwAz_wj7K17IKg3Vn0DFtURdD5_Mxn2xsBAo
Title:TEST
Filename: null
MimeType: application/vnd.google-apps.document
DriveId:DriveId:CAESLDF5c1BVeUdIS3dBel93ajdLMTdJS2czVm4wREZ0VVJkRDVfTXhuMnhzQkFvGKJFIOby8oOMVigA
Description: null
Error while opening the file contents
Status: Status{statusCode=This file is not openable., resolution=null}
Status Code: 10
Status Message: This file is not openable.
```

Comment: same here, but its happens only on Google type doc/sheet/presentation files.

Comment: I read in this link (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/Drive) that just files created or specifically open but the app can be read.
I understand that file created buy google drive in the web won't be able to be readen.